# how do I install Kali or ParrotOS on Mac m2 UTM and store the virtual machine files and virtual disk drive on an external SSD?

Tags: kali-linux, virtual-machine, arm

I already have the proper arm64 iso files from both operating system websites.
for parrot I'm using their arm64 architect version and for Kali I downloaded the arm installer.

during the ParrotOS installation I opened the UTM application and loaded the ISO file into the boot iso section. I allocated the amount of ram, cpu cores, and storage sizes I could give the virtual machine.

I did not see any setting option that would allow me to allocate the virtual disk drive into an external SSD, not in the UTM virtual machine settings nor the installation menu.
After creating a user and password through the graphical install option in the boot menu, I partitioned the drive through all the default options.

I installed all the Operating system correctly and chose which packages to install it rebooted and gave me the install and graphical install menu again. not the login menu. I proceeded with the same steps again to find out at the OS and Package installation steps I got an error saying it couldn't complete this process and I had to delete everything and restart over.

For the kali installation I did the very same thing except I got a black screen after choosing graphical install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a simple straight forward solution to this.

**I am giving the steps from the beginning:**

- install UTM on Mac.
- create required VMs in the UTM following the standard procedures.
- at this point, created VMs complete data is stored at location --> `~/Library/Containers/com.utmapp.UTM/Data/Documents/`.
- for example, in my case, I have created Kali and parrot VMs. So data location of these VMs will be,

  1. `~/Library/Containers/com.utmapp.UTM/Data/Documents/kali.utm` (contains OS + data).
  2. `~/Library/Containers/com.utmapp.UTM/Data/Documents/parrot.utm` (contains OS + data).
- So ideally you just need to move above 2 `.utm` files to your desired destination location. But don't do it manually. Let UTM software do the job. See next step.
- Insert your external harddrive to Mac.
- Now open your UTM dashboard (App). In the left side you see all the VMs.
  Right click on each VM, then select "move" option. After that select the destination location as your external harddrive location. Then click "confirm".
- Now you have moved your VM to your destination location. Also VM data at location `~/Library/Containers/com.utmapp.UTM/Data/Documents/` is removed. Repeat the same for all the VMs.

**NOTE:** UTM software simply needs an `.utm` file. So you can manually keep that file anywhere you want. Open UTM software dashboard. Then open finder and double click on the file which you have copied to open in UTM software. That's it.

**Cons:** You have to do this manually for each VM you create. Anyways we achieved what we want.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the [Kali UTM installation instruction](https://www.kali.org/docs/virtualization/install-utm-guest-vm/) this looks like a UTM issue.

The UTM developers apparently haven't thought about using removable drives for VMs, as it's not an option and the [UTM documentation](https://docs.getutm.app/settings-apple/drive/#removable-drive) only says this:

> Removable Drive
>
> Non-removable drives are stored in the .utm package. Removable drives
> only store a bookmark to the drive image and should be used for ISOs
> and other disk images.

[This UTM GitHub thread](https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/discussions/3355) offers a solution:

> Here I find out a way to solve this problem in a not-that-smart way by using sparse image .A drawback is you must manually mount disk image before using UTM, but you may write a script to do this.
>
> 1. Remember to close you UTM app.
> 2. Open Disk Utility.app and create a new blank sparse disk image and save it on your external drive. For SSD, APFS is recommended while HDD
>    might experience less issues with HFS+ (Mac OS Extended).
> 3. Open Terminal and mount this image at the destination folder by running hdiutil attach /Volumes//.sparseimage -mountpoint
>    ~/Library/Containers/com.utmapp.UTM/Data/Documents in terminal.
> 4. Now you may see a mounted image on your desktop or Finder sidebar. Move all files in
>    ~/Library/Containers/com.utmapp.UTM/Data/Documents to your new disk image.
> 5. Delete the original .utm file, launch your UTM app and your VM now runs in external drive.
>
> Tested with UTM 2.4.1(40) on macOS Monterey 12.0.1 (21A559)

... with feedback:

> Image is an unnecessary abstraction level which may slow down the
> performance. You can just mount a volume into the
> ~/Library/Containers/com.utmapp.UTM/Data/Documents mount point using
> the -mountPoint option of diskutil mount.